# How to set connections-per-host setting in MongoClientSettings?

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive

Blocking MongoDB driver has [`MongoClientOptions`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.html), which contains client settings.
Reactive driver's [`MongoClients.create()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/1.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/reactivestreams/client/MongoClients.html#create-com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings-) expects [`MongoClientSettings`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings.html?is-external=true) as parameter.
Most settings from `MongoClientOptions` have their equivalent in `MongoClientSettings`.

But I can't find `connectionsPerHost` alternative in `MongoClientSettings`.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the connectionsPerHost parameter was changed to ConnectionPoolSettings.maxSize, as part of the new MongoDB driver design. Please take this with a pinch of salt, as I have not tested whether it is a perfectly equivalent option.

The description for `threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier` is as follows, from the MongoDB documentation of [MongoClientSettings.getConnectionPoolSettings](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoClientSettings.html)() the Async driver:

> Gets the settings for the connection provider in a settings object. This settings object wraps the values for minConnectionPoolSize, maxConnectionPoolSize, maxWaitTime, maxConnectionIdleTime and maxConnectionLifeTime, and uses maxConnectionPoolSize and threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier to calculate maxWaitQueueSize.

This behaviour can be observed in [ConnectionPoolSettings.applyConnectionString](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/3.12.x/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/connection/ConnectionPoolSettings.java#L275)():

```
maxWaitQueueSize(threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier * maxSize);
```

This behaviour appears to be similar, when compared to the description for the original [MongoClientOptions.getThreadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.html#getThreadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier--)():

> This multiplier, multiplied with the connectionsPerHost setting, gives the maximum number of threads that may be waiting for a connection to become available from the pool. All further threads will get an exception right away. For example if connectionsPerHost is 10 and threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier is 5, then up to 50 threads can wait for a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Update, in 4.4.X `maxWaitQueueSize` is gone(it is also marked as `@deprecated` in 3.12.X),
I think  `maxConnecting` had replaced it,
so if you are still using the `maxWaitQueueSize` using old logic, the  `maxConnecting` value should be as in the previous answer

```
maxConnecting = maxWaitQueueSize(threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier * maxSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Responding to @Sp193. Following

> threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier

actually covered here [ConnectionString Javadoc](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/javadoc/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.html#getMaxConnectionPoolSize)

- maxPoolSize=n: The maximum number of connections in the connection
  pool.
- waitQueueMultiple=n : this multiplier, multiplied with the
  maxPoolSize setting, gives the maximum number of threads that may be
  waiting for a connection to become available from the pool. All
  further threads will get an exception right away.
- waitQueueTimeoutMS=ms: The maximum wait time in milliseconds that a
  thread may wait for a connection to become available.